# How to insert into foreign key columns in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Maybe this is a stupid question, but I'm kind of stuck here... So I have a table A

```
state | city
MI     Detroit
...
```

And I have a state table B

```
state_id | state
1           MI
...
```

And a city table C

```
city_id | city | state_id
1        Detroit  NULL
```

I want to add a foreign key column in `city` table, I've already created a foreign key column in it with the syntax `ALTER TABLE city ADD CONSTRAINT city_state FOREIGN KEY (state_id) REFERENCES state(state_id);` But the foreign key column was filled with `null` since it doesn't know the relation between city table and the state table.

How can I fill in the foreign key column with right state id? 
Can someone help?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is the `newly created foreign key column`? A foreign key is a constraint on what data you can store, it doesn't create any new columns or data. Also, your tags are conflicting (mysql & postgresql).

Comment: I've updated the question. The city table should be city_id, city, state_id. But with the above `ALTER TABLE` syntax the state_id column is only filled with NULL

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are really using.

Comment: Now your design doesn't make much sense. I'd think you'd want one table with (state_id, state) and one table (city, state_id).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `join` in an `update`.  In Postgres this looks like:

```
update city
   set state_id = b.state_id
   from a join
        b
        on a.state = b.state
   where city.city = a.city;
```

In MySQL:

```
update city join
       a
       on city.city = a.city join
       b
       on a.state = b.state
   set city.state_id = b.state_id;
```

Answer (score -1):

You SQL code for Mysql is:

```
CREATE TABLE city (
    city_id int NOT NULL,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    state_id int,
    PRIMARY KEY (city_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (state_id) REFERENCES state(state_id)
);
```

And if you want add a new row with a reference to another row in the state`s table, you need add the id of this row, example:

```
INSERT INTO city VALUES  (1, "Los Angeles", 1);
```

1 will be a id from state table!